# Get the global memory maximum available for Docker in windows, within powershell

Tags: powershell, docker

I would like to write a script that checks that Docker has access to a minimum X amount of memory, on Windows. I need this to work with Docker running on Hyper-V.

Get-VM with hyper-v gives me memory assigned for the DockerDesktopVM of 0, I assume because it's using dynamic memory allocation. But I know Docker does have a maximum set to the memory available, i.e. the same memory limit discussed in questions like [Docker won't start on Windows- Not enough memory to start Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43170089/docker-wont-start-on-windows-not-enough-memory-to-start-docker)

Is there some way to get the memory limit assigned to the Docker container from within powershell or the command line?

Answer (score 3):

Of course as soon as I asked this I found it.

```
(Get-VMMemory DockerDesktopVM).Startup
```