# Error starting DockerDesktopVM on Windows 10 "unable to allocate 2048 MB of RAM"

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-desktop

Every time I try to start Docker now I get this error message.  In typical style, the Docker support team is not responding with helpful hints or a fix, other than "Try Resetting to Factory Settings", which results in a similar error (see below).

I have 32 GB RAM installed in a Windows 10 (Build v10.0.18363 Build 18363) on Dell Precision 7530 laptop hardware.   I am NOT using Windows 10 WSL.

I am running Docker Desktop Community Edition v2.2.05 (43884) Channel "Stable" with Engine 19.03.8, Compose v1.25.4:

**What I Have Tried to Solve the Problem**

1) "Resetting" DockerDesktop to Factory Settings is the recommended solution, which is very heavy handed since it can effectively remove all containers and images.  But this does not help.  This gives a variant of the same error message.  (see error messages far below)

2) Uninstalling and reinstalling the latest version of DockerDesktop CE works for a while, but then the same error starts again without any indication of why.  Rebooting Windows 10 to free up more RAM does not help.

> Docker.Core.DockerException:
>   Docker.Core.Backend.BackendDestroyException: Unable to start Hyper-V
>   VM: 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start.
>
> Unable to allocate 2048 MB of RAM: Insufficient system resources exist
>   to complete the requested service. (0x800705AA).
>
> 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID
>   6C60E2ED-5F89-433A-B932-32D715F52FDA)
>
> 'DockerDesktopVM' is unable to allocate 2048 MB of RAM: Insufficient
>   system resources exist to complete the requested service.
>   (0x800705AA). (Virtual machine ID
>   6C60E2ED-5F89-433A-B932-32D715F52FDA) at Start-MobyLinuxVM, :
>   line 688 at , : line 811    at
>   Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings, String
>   daemonOptions, Credential credential)    at
>   Docker.Backend.BackendNamedPipeServer.b__8_2(Object[] args)    at
>   Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(Object[]
>   parameters)    at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String
>   action, Object[] parameters)
>
> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException:   Unable to start
>   Hyper-V VM: 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start.
>
> Unable to allocate 2048 MB of RAM: Insufficient system resources exist
>   to complete the requested service. (0x800705AA).
>        'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID 6C60E2ED-5F89-433A-B932-32D715F52FDA)
>
> 'DockerDesktopVM' is unable to allocate 2048 MB of RAM: Insufficient
>   system resources exist to complete the requested service.
>   (0x800705AA). (Virtual machine ID
>   6C60E2ED-5F89-433A-B932-32D715F52FDA)   at Start-MobyLinuxVM, : line 688   at , : line 811
>        at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.DoStart(Settings settings, String daemonOptions, Credential credential)
>        at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings, String daemonOptions, Credential credential)
>
> ```
>  Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VirtualizationException:
>  'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start.
> ```
>
> Unable to allocate 2048 MB of RAM: Insufficient system resources exist
>   to complete the requested service. (0x800705AA).
>
> ```
>  'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID 6C60E2ED-5F89-433A-B932-32D715F52FDA)
> ```
>
> 'DockerDesktopVM' is unable to allocate 2048 MB of RAM: Insufficient
>   system resources exist to complete the requested service.
>   (0x800705AA). (Virtual machine ID
>   6C60E2ED-5F89-433A-B932-32D715F52FDA)
>
> ```
>      Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.VirtualizationOperationFailedException:
>      'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start.
> ```
>
> Unable to allocate 2048 MB of RAM: Insufficient system resources exist
>   to complete the requested service. (0x800705AA).
>               at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.View.EndMethodReturnInternal(IVMTask
>   task, VirtualizationOperation operation, Boolean
>   affectedElementExpected)
>               at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.VMComputerSystemBaseView.EndSetState(IVMTask
>   setStateTask)
>               at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.ExtensionMethods.OperationWatcherExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.<ConvertActionToFunction>b__0(T
>   x)
>               at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.ExtensionMethods.OperationWatcherExtensions.PerformOperationWithReturn[T](IOperationWatcher
>   watcher, Func`1 startTaskMethod, Func`2 endTaskMethod, String
>   taskDescription, VirtualizationObject targetObject)
>               at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VirtualMachine.ChangeState(VirtualMachineAction
>   action, IOperationWatcher operationWatcher)
>               at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.StartVM.ProcessOneOperand(VirtualMachine
>   vm, IOperationWatcher operationWatcher)
>               at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.VirtualizationCmdlet`1.ProcessOperands(IList`1
>   operands, IOperationWatcher operationWatcher)
>                at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[]
>   parameters)    at Docker.Actions.DoStart(SynchronizationContext
>   syncCtx, Boolean showWelcomeWindow, Boolean withNotifications)    at
>   Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.b__0()    at
>   Docker.ApiServices.TaskQueuing.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<.ctor>b__1()

#

This is not a Hyper-V issue either because when I try to start DockerDesktopVM after starting Hyper-V in Windows 10, I get the following error from DockerDesktopVM:

#

> Hyper-V Manager  An error occurred while attempting to start the 
>   selected virtual machine(s).  'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start. 
>   Unable to allocate 2C48 MB of RAM: Insufficient system  resources
>   exist to complete the requested service. (Dx8D0705AA). 
>   'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID  6C60E2ED-5F8-g
>   433A 8932 32D715F52FDA)  'DockerDesktopVM' is unable to allocate 2C48
>   MB of RAM:  Insufficient system resources exist to complete the
>   requested  service. (Dx8D0705AA). (Virtual machine ID  6C60E2ED-5F8-g
>   433A 8932 32D715F52FDA)
>
> ##################################################

After the "Resetting DockerDesktop" operation I get basically the same error result.

#

> Docker.Core.DockerException: Docker.Core.Backend.BackendException:
>   Unable to start Hyper-V VM: 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start.
>
> Unable to allocate 2048 MB of RAM: Insufficient system resources exist
>   to complete the requested service. (0x800705AA).
>
> 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID
>   6C60E2ED-5F89-433A-B932-32D715F52FDA)
>
> 'DockerDesktopVM' is unable to allocate 2048 MB of RAM: Insufficient
>   system resources exist to complete the requested service.
>   (0x800705AA). (Virtual machine ID
>   6C60E2ED-5F89-433A-B932-32D715F52FDA) at Start-MobyLinuxVM, :
>   line 688 at , : line 811
>
> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException:   Unable to start
>   Hyper-V VM: 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start.
>
> Unable to allocate 2048 MB of RAM: Insufficient system resources exist
>   to complete the requested service. (0x800705AA).
>        'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID 6C60E2ED-5F89-433A-B932-32D715F52FDA)
>
> 'DockerDesktopVM' is unable to allocate 2048 MB of RAM: Insufficient
>   system resources exist to complete the requested service.
>   (0x800705AA). (Virtual machine ID
>   6C60E2ED-5F89-433A-B932-32D715F52FDA)   at Start-MobyLinuxVM, : line 688   at , : line 811
>        at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.DoStart(Settings settings, String daemonOptions, Credential credential)
>        at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Restart(Settings settings, String daemonOptions, Credential credential)
>        at Docker.Backend.BackendNamedPipeServer.b__8_3(Object[] args)
>        at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(Object[]
>   parameters)
>        at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action, Object[] parameters)
>
> ```
>  Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VirtualizationException:
>  'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start.
> ```
>
> Unable to allocate 2048 MB of RAM: Insufficient system resources exist
>   to complete the requested service. (0x800705AA).
>
> ```
>  'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID 6C60E2ED-5F89-433A-B932-32D715F52FDA)
> ```
>
> 'DockerDesktopVM' is unable to allocate 2048 MB of RAM: Insufficient
>   system resources exist to complete the requested service.
>   (0x800705AA). (Virtual machine ID
>   6C60E2ED-5F89-433A-B932-32D715F52FDA)
>
> ```
>      Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.VirtualizationOperationFailedException:
>      'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start.
> ```
>
> Unable to allocate 2048 MB of RAM: Insufficient system resources exist
>   to complete the requested service. (0x800705AA).
>               at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.View.EndMethodReturnInternal(IVMTask
>   task, VirtualizationOperation operation, Boolean
>   affectedElementExpected)
>               at Microsoft.Virtualization.Client.Management.VMComputerSystemBaseView.EndSetState(IVMTask
>   setStateTask)
>               at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.ExtensionMethods.OperationWatcherExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.<ConvertActionToFunction>b__0(T
>   x)
>               at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.ExtensionMethods.OperationWatcherExtensions.PerformOperationWithReturn[T](IOperationWatcher
>   watcher, Func`1 startTaskMethod, Func`2 endTaskMethod, String
>   taskDescription, VirtualizationObject targetObject)
>               at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VirtualMachine.ChangeState(VirtualMachineAction
>   action, IOperationWatcher operationWatcher)
>               at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.StartVM.ProcessOneOperand(VirtualMachine
>   vm, IOperationWatcher operationWatcher)
>               at Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.VirtualizationCmdlet`1.ProcessOperands(IList`1
>   operands, IOperationWatcher operationWatcher)
>                at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[]
>   parameters)    at Docker.Actions.DoRestartVM(Settings
>   previousSettings)    at
>   Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass34_0.b__0()    at
>   Docker.ApiServices.TaskQueuing.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<.ctor>b__1()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker won't start on Windows: Not Enough memory to start docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43170089/docker-wont-start-on-windows-not-enough-memory-to-start-docker)

Comment: After about 5 updates to Docker Desktop for Windows, this error stopped.  Although they are interesting suggestions, none of the other answers here worked.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried increase the amount of memory used by docker?

Tray menu docker -> Preferences -> resources

[image]

Comment: Yes, I tried that.  Docker resets it back to 2GB the next time it runs (and crashes).

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error.  I opened the Hyper-V Manager and increased the amount of RAM allocated to the DockerDesktopVM image from 2048 to 4096.  When I next ran Docker Desktop, it started correctly, though it reset the assigned memory back to 2048.