# Docker can't pull postgres image: "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.22000 in the manifest list entries"

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

i'm creating a new django project and my DB is Postgresql. it was fine and everything was ok until one day when i tried to start docker i saw this: "Not enough memory to start docker". I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45816385/19352984) and it worked and docker desktop started perfectly. but now when i'm trying to run `docker-compose up` i get this:

```
[+] Running 0/1
 - db Pulling                                                                                     3.3s
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.22000 in the manifest list entries
```

this is docker-compose.yml db part:

```
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
```

I even tried `docker pull postgres:14` but it's same:

```
14: Pulling from library/postgres
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.22000 in the manifest list entries
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Switch to Windows containers` means your docker now ready to run `windows containers`, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/run-your-first-container).

> no matching manifest for windows/amd64

This means you are trying to running `postgres` which only support linux containers on windows containers, definitely you will have the error.

Back to the post you found, it also mentioned next:

> PS: Switching back to Linux container should work now after switching to Windows Containers for most of the users as said by rfay.

So, please switch back to linux containers again to see if any magic there, otherwise, you will have to increase your memory (Or maybe you could try to stop other hyper-v machine to reduce the system memory usage).

Comment: I switched back to linux containers and it worked perfectly. thanks for your help